# Why doesn't the line number match the actual number in csv file?

Tags: python, csv

I have a file with such lines:

```
$ wc -l ../data/raw_data/query.ws.csv 
 2000096 ../data/raw_data/query.ws.csv
```

However, when I read the csv file and count the lines, it doesn't match:

```
line_number = 0
with open(filename) as cfile:
    csv_file = csv.reader(cfile)

    for row in csv_file:
        line_number += 1

logger.info("Total lines: {}".format(str(line_number)))
```

The log info:

```
wbnp - INFO - 64 - Total lines: 1366330
```

Why isn't it equal 2000096? I checked in vim and found it doesn't contain any blank lines.

Comment: it's possible for a single csv row to span multiple lines.  if this is the case here, you should be able to see this by printing out each csv row along with its "line number", or by checking each csv row to see if it has a newline.

Comment: In vim, that should be counted as one line, right? In vim, it shows 2000096

Comment: vim is doing the same thing as wc in this case: it's looking at lines, not interpreting csv data.

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values for more info

Comment: It's not really a csv file. It's a regular plain text and it read it as a csv file, treating it as a one-column csv file. That's the problem?

Comment: @ling Why are you reading it as a CSV? Can you share some information on the format of the data?

Comment: yes. I shouldn't use csv when it's plain text.